# difference between MPL and PayPal iOS SDK

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to integrate my app with PayPal. I integrated using PayPal iOS SDK but i m facing some issues as in iOS SDK it doesn't have full support for non-US developers. I want to know what's difference between MPL and PayPal iOS SDK.

What are the advantages of PayPal iOS SDK over MPL ?
What are the disadvantages of PayPal iOS SDK over MPL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

The main distinction is that MPL is an older SDK which PayPal is phasing out, while the PayPal iOS SDK (mobile SDK, or "mSDK") is a new SDK which PayPal is phasing in. mSDK is based on the new [REST APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/), which themselves are under active development.

For simple one-time payment transactions, mSDK is easier to integrate into your app than MPL.

However, during this transition period, MPL includes several features that have not yet been implemented for mSDK. These features include pre-approved payments, chained payments, and more support for non-U.S. accounts.

There is also a third option, the [Mobile Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MEC/) ("MEC"). This is a webflow-based approach.

Some relevant links: SDKs Overview[1], MPL[2], MEC[3]

[1] https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/
[2] https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/
[3] https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MEC/#concepts

Comment: Thanks for Dave am also Plan to develope and Android app with Paypal Integration:As per your conversation MPL is Older and Android/IOS sdk are the new one.we i need to use relevant mobile sdk.while using mobile sdks is any need of app id am testing with sand box without using app id but i have little confuse please help me.

Comment: @Harsha for the new SDKs, as documented [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#credentials), you need to specify your `client_id`. No other identifier is needed.